# react-router tutorial not working on mac

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, react-router

I tried to get into **react** following the **[react tutorials](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html)** and got it working, but when I started to go to the next step and use **react-router** through **[this tutorial](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/01-setting-up)** I failed every time!

When I follow the instructions everything seems to be working OK, no errors on terminal, but I don't see any **bundle.js** files created in my project folder nor the **localhost:8080** shows anything other than the following error in console:

> GET http://localhost:8080/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I tried installing **npm** locally and globally but none worked, same as **webpack**. Also I tried running the servers using **webpack** with the code `webpack ./index.js bundle.js` doesn't work either and throws the following error in terminal:

> ERROR in multi main
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'bundle.js' in /Users/jafari/Desktop/React-Toturial/react-router-tutorial/lessons/01-setting-up
>    @ multi main

While this code creates the **bundle.js** file and if I run this folder through **MAMP** on the localhost I can see the desired content of the tutorial, when I change anything in the **App.js** it doesn't take effect until I remove the **bundle.js** and do the process I mentioned earlier again in the terminal while still seeing the following error in the console:

> bundle.js:49 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "bundle.js"

And if I don't remove **bundle.js** I get this error in the console:

> Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server:(client) `<div data-reactid="`(server) `<div data-reactid="`

Any ideas? or alternatively any suggestion or tutorial on how to use **react-router**?

Comment: I can't replicate your error, but have you tried changing the port 8080 to something else? Also, you are not seeing bundle.js because npm start is using webpack-dev-server

Comment: yes I did, although after executing `npm start` it prompts to go to `localhost:8080`

Comment: thats strange... how did you change the port? Did you execute the command _webpack-dev-server --port 3000 --inline --content-base_ ? (you can replace the npm start script in your package json with that command)

Comment: oh that got it working! changing the port and running the project with webpack-dev-server instead of npm start, if you post your comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the port to something else with the command `webpack-dev-server --port 3000 --inline --content-base`

You can also substitute the `npm start` script in the **package.json** with that line.